# jQuery .click not running

Tags: jquery

**Hello Stackers**

I'm having a problem with a CLICK action. It just doesn't work, it doesn't run the Click. When Clicking, it just does nothing. Not even returning an Error. Is the Click wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("notclicked");
    $("#makesee-<?php echo $n['id']; ?>").click(function() 

{
    console.log("clickerdeclick");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "seenot.php",
        async: true,
        data: { a: <?php echo $n['id']; ?> , b:<?php echo $user['id']; ?>},
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            console.log("twerkt");
        },
        error: function (response) {

            //if error output data in console
            console.log(response);
            console.log("lol");
        }
    });
});
});
```

And this is my button,

```
<a class="btn btn-default" id="#makeseen-<?php echo $n['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></a></button>
```

Comment: Please take a look at your rendered page, by running your application and then using 'View page source' in the browser. So you can clarify what's the final html/js code

Comment: There are no console errors.

Comment: Your `id` attribute shouldn't have a `#` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the ID attribut to not have PHP code in it.

Do something like this instead (if you need the ID from PHP:

```
<a class="btn btn-default myButton" data-id="<?php echo $n['id']; ?>">
```

Then you use this jQuery:

```
$(".myButton").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "seenot.php",
        async: true,
        data: {"a": id },
        ...
        etc
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I Understand, however, it's in a WHILE, because it's a long list of same elements. Without the ID, how can jQuery recognize that that exact button is clicked?

Comment: You bind the click event to the class, not the ID. Hence it will trigger on a click on any button with that specific class. You then use $(this) to get a reference to the actual button clicked and can read the data-id (or any other attributes you want to use).

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly that wat I needed. It did fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid mixing PHP and Javascript.

#### Button

```
<button>
  <a class="btn btn-default" id="makeseen-<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true">Click Me</span>
  </a>
</button>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert($(this).children("a").data("id"));
  });
});
```

#### Fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm9f5scx/1/)